# tableview to a detail view which shows another table view and could have its own detail view

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a table view which shows a table view and has a detail view.  In that detail view I have a need to show a list to choose from which is best from a table and could have a detail view.  The last set of table view/detail view needs to inform the first detail view the row that the user selected?
I have a navcontroller, used mastercontroller concept to get to the detail view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether it could be first level or second level child view controller, it is always better to use `delegates` (@Protocol) to callback the parent view controller.

A simple tutorial on that can be found [here](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/objective-c/the-basics-of-protocols-and-delegates.html)

Comment: thanks, the delegate protocols works great and am now using that wherever possible.